# C# Dictionary, what is the source of TryGetValue error in this simple code

Tags: c#

```
        Dictionary<string, int> test = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        test.Add("dave", 12);
        test.Add("john", 14);

        int v;

        test.TryGetValue("dave", out int v)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(v);

        }
```

This simple C# code gives "Best Overload Method Match has some Invalid Arguments" error.  Can you please tell me the source of the error?  Thanks.

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using? VS2017 likes that code just fine, once I fix the syntax error. Please post complete, valid example code that reliably reproduces the issue in some specific, named version of the compiler.

Comment: `out int value` is C# 7 only

Comment: Are you missing an `if` statement around `test.TryGetValue`?

Comment: @haim770 That error will be "invalid expression term int", not anything about the overload.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012.  I still receive the error despite the edits mentioned below.  Thank you.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> test = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            test.Add("dave", 12);
            test.Add("john", 14);
            int v;

            test.TryGetValue("dave", out int v)
            {
         
                Console.WriteLine(v);

            }
           
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, that's very hard to read. I've edited your question to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  It appears it's my compiler version causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is in VS2012, not using C#7.

First, get rid of `int` in the parameter list. It can't be there in your version of C#.

Second, put a semicolon after the TryGetValue() call...

```
int v;
test.TryGetValue("dave", out v);
Console.WriteLine(v);
```

Or put it in an if:

```
int v;
if (test.TryGetValue("dave", out v))
{ 
     Console.WriteLine(v); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "value" a variable you already declared or did you leave the example from the intellisense for TryGetValue? Pretty sure it's the latter case. edit: OR it's a new version of C# feature... This writes out 12 for v:

```
            Dictionary<string, int> test = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                    test.Add("dave", 12);
                    test.Add("john", 14);

                    int v;
                    test.TryGetValue("dave", out v);
                {
                            Console.WriteLine(v);

                    }
```

Comment: As others pointed out, your version uses this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating it with the Roslyn compiler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eblkGk

Comment: I never knew there was a dotnet fiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You got either a typo or a misunderstanding of

```
TryGetValue()
```

There is no need for the code block where your writeline sits in.
Just end your line of code and do your writeLine.

```
test.TryGetValue("dave", out int value); // <---- notice the ;
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

EDIT:
Or, as Mr.Nimelo suggests, there might be an if statement missing like so:

```
if test.TryGetValue("dave", out int value) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you miss an `if` in your snippet, nope?

```
    Dictionary<string, int> test = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    test.Add("dave", 12);
    test.Add("john", 14);

    // missing if there?
    test.TryGetValue("dave", out int value)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(value);

    }
```

My cheap 2 cents with a bit of refactoring...:

```
    var test = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"dave", 12}, {"john", 14}};

    if (test.TryGetValue("dave", out var value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```